# run npm script after package installing

Tags: npm, webpack

I have a simple git repository https://github.com/alexey-sh/test_webpack_with_npm

I want to use it as npm dependency but without publishing in npm.

So in other words I want to install the package in my another repository as dependency.

`npm i --save git+https://github.com/alexey-sh/test_webpack_with_npm.git`

But I want to use a modern js in my `test_webpack_with_npm` project and compile it into old javascript after package installation process. To achieve it I created npm scripts (test_webpack_with_npm package)

```
  "scripts": {
    "install": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

so now there's a weird thing:
if I run `npm run build` from `test_webpack_with_npm` repository I can get `dist/index.js` without `class` declaration (as I expected).
but if I install the package via the following command 
`npm i --save git+https://github.com/alexey-sh/test_webpack_with_npm.git`
I get another type of `dist/index.js` and there are `class` declaration.

How can I install the `test_webpack_with_npm` properly? I want to see old js in `node_modules/test_webpack_with_npm/dist/index.js`.

Steps to reproduce:

- `mkdir my_test_project`
- `cd my_test_project`
- `npm init`
- `npm i --save git+https://github.com/alexey-sh/test_webpack_with_npm.git`
- check node_modules/test_webpack_with_npm/dist/index.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix is very simple. just replace exclude with include in webpack config

`include: path.join(__dirname, 'sources'),`

that works perfectly.

updated config goes here https://github.com/alexey-sh/test_webpack_with_npm/blob/master/webpack.config.js